# Compounding some arbitrary Regexes (Or, are many small Regexes better than one big one)

Tags: c#, regex, performance

I have a number of user defined `Regex`es that I'm using to test some `string`s to see If I should exclude them.

```
private readonly IEnumerable<Regex> exclusions = <some user defined source>;

static bool Exclude(string value)
{
    return this.exclusions.Any(regex => regex.IsMatch(value);
}
```

I'm thinking, is there some way to compound the set of `exclusions` into a single combined `exclusion` `Regex` which would allow me to remove the iteration from the `Exclude` function, like this.

```
static bool Exclude(string value)
{
    return this.exclusion.IsMatch(value);
}
```

Is this approach feasible, would it have a potential performance benefit or is it just pushing the burden of iteration down into the Regex processor?

---

**EDIT**

So, I could simply do,

```
var exclusion =
    new Regex(string.Join("|", exclusions.Select(e => e.ToString()));
```

Is there any more sophisticated option?

---

**EDIT 2**

I've decided that since I have no control over the regular expressions, combining them blind is a naive approach, more likely to result in bugs than improved performance.

Comment: The current approach only executes regexes until it finds a match. I don't think there is any performance benefit to compounding the regexes, and -most likely- it will be slower. And the code won't be any prettier.
So my question is: why do you want to do this?

Comment: @MennovandenHeuvel I only want to do it if there is potenetial performance benefit. I'm stuck on the idea that a combined regular expression could find a match sooner than enumerating a set of simpler regexes. As you highlight, this is predicated on the match being processed later.

Comment: What would be more sophisticated?  Maybe you could provide an example of 2 regexes and a combination of them that does not use | and better suits your needs?

Comment: @mbeckish I probably could but, the approach wouldn't work generically. I can envisage other situations where a generic approach could lead to problems, I have edited my question accordingly and credited your efforts too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical OR:

```
regex1 | regex2 | ...
```

Comment: So, somthing like `var exclusion = new Regex(string.Join("|", exclusions.Select(e => e.ToString()));`

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you'd want to do that, your current code looks ok to me, but I think you can take all the strings defining your regexs and combine them into one like that:

```
(?:(?:REGEX1)|(?:REGEX2)|(?:REGEX3)|(?:REGEX4))
```

Comment: excuse my ignorance, what are the `?:` parts of the regex doing?

Comment: ?: defines a non-capturing group.